# Set initialValue formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I am currently using formik to build a form, but when I use nested object inside initialValues like this :
`address:{title:"this a title",value:{principalAddress:"test",seconderyAddress:""}}`

I can't access to principalAdress in formik field when I set the name of the field

```
<Field component={TextField} fullWidth type="text" name="value. seconderyAddress"/>.
```

if there s someone who can help me I will be thankful.

Comment: please share your entire `initialValues` object

Comment: @thedude i share it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the Field's name to: `address.value.principalAddress`

```
<Field component={TextField} fullWidth type="text" name="address.value.principalAddress"/>
```